# Find offset in table with order and where clause

Tags: sqlite

Consider the following schema and table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `names` (
    `id`    INTEGER,
    `name`  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (1,'zulu');
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (2,'bene');
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (3,'flip');
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (4,'rossB');
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (5,'albert');
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (6,'zuse');
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (7,'rossA');
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES (8,'juss');
```

I access this table with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM names
ORDER BY name
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 4;
```

Where offset 4 is used because it's the rowid (in the ordered list) to the first occurance of 'R%' names.  This returns:

```
1="7"   "rossA"
2="4"   "rossB"
3="1"   "zulu"
4="6"   "zuse"
```

My question is, is there an SQL statement which can return the OFFSET value (in the R case above its 4) given a starting first letter please?  (I don't really want to resort to stepping() through results, counting rows, until first 'R%' is reached!)

I've tried the following without success:

```
SELECT MIN(ROWID)
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM names
    ORDER BY name
)
WHERE name LIKE 'R%'
```

It always returns single row of NULL data.

As background, this table is a phone book list and I want to provide subset of results (from main table) back to caller, starting at a initial letter offset.

Answer (score 1):

Just count the rows before the string of interest:

```
select count(*) from names where name < 'r';
```

Answer (score 0):

The following has a number of options. Basically your issues is that the sub-query doesn't return the **roiwd** hencne NULL as the minimum. However, there is no need to use the rowid directly as the **id** column is an alias of the **rowid**, so that could be used:-

```
SELECT name, id, MIN(rowid), min(id) -- shows how rowid and id are the same
FROM
(
    SELECT rowid, * -- returns rowid from the subquery so min(rowid) now works
    FROM names
    ORDER BY name
)
WHERE name LIKE 'R%' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 -- Will effectivley do the same (no need for the sub-query)
```

[image]

- Extra columns added for demonstration.

#### As such your query could be :-

```
SELECT min(rowid) FROM names where name LIKE 'R%';
```

[image]

### Or :-

```
SELECT min(id) FROM names where name LIKE 'R%';
```

[image]

You could also use :-

```
SELECT id FROM names WHERE name LIKE 'R%' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Or :-

```
SELECT rowid FROM names WHERE name LIKE 'R%' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for tip on getting MIN(ROWID) working, but this isn't giving the result I'm looking for, unfortunately.  Offset '4' for R% was actually a bad example..  Try it for 'A%', which should return 0 (not 5), B%=1, F%=2, J%=3 etc.  I want row id in ordered table, not id associated with entry.